# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes (unable to use either the keyboard or the mouse) on HP 14s-cr1005TU laptop

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, freeze, crash

The laptop runs on a intel HD 620 graphics card. I tried the nomodeset, which helped me pass through the login but still the computer doesn't let me move the mouse or use my keyboard within minutes. Please help.